# Uploading a video to youtube from a ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api

Is there any gem to directly upload a youtube video from a Rails Web app? Can you point me out to that gem or is there any good tutorials explaining how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Youtube_It](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) looks quite comprehensive. Plus they have an [example Rails app](https://github.com/chebyte/youtube_it_rails_app_example) to help you set it up.

Comment: there is no good tutorial for it, finding it really difficult. Can you help? Is there any good tutorial?

Comment: The gem is documented quite well in the Readme. There is no tutorial that is going to spoon feed it for you, you'll have to dig in and try it out, if you run into some errors ask a new question here and people would be happy to help.

Comment: I am quite new so I barely understand how to initialize a new client and all that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well then I suggest cloning the example repo from the github I linked and just playing around with it and trying to modify it to your needs.